# Animations with React JS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, reactjs

I have a few sort filters on my page, and I want to create animation when user click on one of them.

If user want to sort by the lowest price, I want to show the new list, but with some animations.

I try to do it with React JS.

On componentWillMount I set the state with all cars :

```
componentWillMount(){
    const cart = this.props.cart;
    const listID = this.props.params.id;
    const allCars = data.getAllCars();
    let offers = this.state.offers;

    cart.map(car => {
        const aCar = allCars.find(c => {
            return c.id === car.carID;
        });
        offers[aCar.chassis] = car.offer;
        this.setState({offers: offers});
    });


    //We set state with all cars in this list
    const cars = carData.getCarsInCurrentList(listID, allCars);
    this.setState({cars: cars});
}
```

and then when user clicks on one of the sort filters I handle it on this function :

```
handleSortingFilters(name, event){

    event.preventDefault();
    const cars = this.state.cars;
    const sortFilterValue = this.state.sortFiltersInit[name];
    let filteredCars = "";

    if(sortFilterValue){
        //descending order
        filteredCars = cars.sort((a, b) => {
            if(name === "initialRegistration"){
                return Date.parse(b[name]) - Date.parse(a[name]);
            }else{
                return parseFloat(b[name]) - parseFloat(a[name]);
            }
        });
    }else{
        //ascending order
        filteredCars = cars.sort((a, b) => {
            if(name === "initialRegistration") {
                return Date.parse(a[name]) - Date.parse(b[name]);
            }else{
                return parseFloat(a[name]) - parseFloat(b[name]);
            }

        });
    }

    let sortFiltersInit = this.state.sortFiltersInit;
    sortFiltersInit[name] = !this.state.sortFiltersInit[name];

    let allFilters = this.state.allFilters;
    allFilters[name] = name;

    this.setState({cars: filteredCars, sortFiltersInit: sortFiltersInit, allFilters: allFilters});
}
```

Thus, I update the state with the filtered list of cars. Everything works perfect, but I would like also to apply some css animations on the list when user clicks on one of the sort filters.

Any ideas or link to some good tutorials?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The list where the cars are rendered :

```
<div className="cars">
            <div>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName="example"
                transitionAppear={true}
                transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>

                {cars.map((car, i) => {
                    const initialReg = car.initialRegistration.slice(0,3) + car.initialRegistration.slice(6,10);
                    // str.slice(1, 4) extracts the second character through the fourth character (characters indexed 1, 2, and 3)

                    return (
                        <div key={i} className="carBox noPadding">
                            <div className="carBoxContent">

                                <PhotoAndFavorites car={car} language={language} changeStarIcon={this.changeStarIcon} addToFavorites={addToFavorites} userEmail={currentUserEmail} favorites={favorites}/>

                                <div className="carNameAndDesc">
                                    <div><Link to="" style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>{car.make}</Link></div>
                                    <div>{car.desc}</div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="carPrice">
                                    <div>{car.price}</div>
                                    <div>{car.btw}</div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="extraFeatures" style={{marginBottom: 5, backgroundColor: '#eee'}}>

                                </div>

                                <div className="mainFeatures">
                                    <div><img src="../images/portal/user/status/fuel-icon.png" style={{height: 12}}/> <span>{car.fuel}</span></div>
                                    <div><img src="../images/portal/user/status/road-icon.png" style={{height: 12}}/> <span>{car.mileage}</span></div>
                                    <div><img src="../images/portal/user/status/calendar-icon.png" style={{height: 12}}/> <span>{initialReg}</span></div>
                                </div>

                                <Buttons car={car}
                                         language={language}
                                         changeButton={this.changeButton}
                                         addToCard={addToCard}
                                         removeFromCard={removeFromCard}
                                         cartContent={cartContent}
                                         userEmail={currentUserEmail}
                                         handleChange={handleOffers}
                                         offers={offers}
                                         opacity={this.props.opacity}
                                         />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
            <div className="clearfix"/>
        </div>
```

I added also this css :

```
 .example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [react-addons-css-transition-group](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

> `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is based on `ReactTransitionGroup` and is an
>   easy way to perform CSS transitions and animations when a React
>   component enters or leaves the DOM. It's inspired by the excellent
>   ng-animate library.

This will trigger a transition in your main layout every time you change a route

**css**

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'

render() {
  return(
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      component="ul"
      transitionName="example"
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
      {this.state.cars.map(car => <li key={car.id}>{car.name}</li>)}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  )
}
```

If you need a shuffle animation try [react-shuffle](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-shuffle) - Animated shuffling of child components

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Shuffle from 'react-shuffle';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Shuffle>
        {// Method to render children goes here}
      </Shuffle>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added what you said, but it isn't working. See the updated question.

Comment: If you want the animation also on the initial call you need to add the 'transitionAppear={true}' prop! Your example is not working, cause you render the transition group and the content on the same time.

Comment: Forgot: you need also transitionAppearTimeout={500} 
More information:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#animate-initial-mounting

Comment: It works on page load. But I want that my list order is shuffled if I click on one of those filters. Now if I click on the filter there is no animation.

Comment: I tried this, but I get warning `bundle.js:8394 Warning: Unknown props `duration`, `fade`, `initial` on <div> tag.`

Comment: It worked. The trick was _The only real requirement is that each child has a non-index based key, for proper position identification._